# How do I wait for a thread to finish in Qt without blocking its execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a function that creates a bunch of QThreads to speed up a long calculation, but when I try and sleep until the calculation is done, the background threads never execute for some reason.

I can't figure out why the threads don't execute after I call `thread->start()`. Here's my code:

```
multithread.run_multithread(run_function, thread_count);
while(multithread.running)
    QThread::msleep(100);
qDebug() << "done";  // Never reaches this point
```

And the multithread function:

```
void Multithread::run_multithread(std::function<void
 (int)>run_function_in, int thread_count) {
    running = true;
    // Create workers and threads
    int thread_idx;
    for(thread_idx=0; thread_idx<thread_count; thread_idx++) {
        ThreadWorker *worker = new ThreadWorker(this, run_function_in);
        QThread *thread = new QThread();
        // Set workers and threads to delete when done
        worker->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(worker, &ThreadWorker::finished, this, &Multithread::check_progress);
        connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &ThreadWorker::run);
        connect(worker, &ThreadWorker::finished, thread, &QThread::quit);
        connect(worker, &ThreadWorker::finished, worker, &ThreadWorker::deleteLater);
        connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
        // Start thread
        thread->start();
    }
}
```

`running` gets set to `false` in `Multithread::check_progress` when all the threads finish their part of the calculation. When I remove `QThread::msleep(100)` the calculation will execute normally, but I need some way to block until it completes.

Comment: Instead of blocking, you might consider having each thread fire a signal to indicate its completion. Then you just need a slot that counts the number of times it's been called so you know when the calculations are complete.

Comment: @MrEricSir I would do that if I could, but I need to perform the multithread calculation several times sequentially within one function, so it would be difficult to keep track of which point I was at every time the multithread calculation finished. Also, I feel like there's some obvious concept that I'm not getting. I don't understand why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using QThread, I would recommend using the Qt Concurrent functionality which provides a higher level of abstraction over the thread primitives. You can use `QFutureSynchronizer` to wait for several concurrent futures to finish. This object will wait for all attached futures to finish before it allows itself to be destroyed.

An example of how to start several threads and then wait for them all to finish is:

```
#include <QtConcurrent>

void run_multithread(...) {
  // Set up a new synchronizer.
  QFutureSynchronizer<void> synchronizer;

  // Run n tasks in parallel.
  for (int thread_idx = 0; thread_idx < thread_count; ++thread_idx) {
    synchronizer.addFuture(QtConcurrent::run(run_function_in));
  }

  // The synchroniser will wait for all threads to finish before returning.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of optimization, since `multithread.running` is not changed inside the loop. However, here the main reproducible reason is that the slot `Multithread::check_progress` is never called by `ThreadWorker::finished` signals, since the instance of `Multithread` belongs to your current thread, but the event loop is blocked.

Instead of such sleep you can emit a signal from `Multithread` object when all threads are finished. Then the computation may be continued from a slot connected to that signal.